# Can I cite in a caption?

Tags: citations, writing, graphics

I am using an image from a users’ manual of a piece of software, and I was wondering if I can put a citation in the caption of the image. For example:

> **Figure 1.3** Illustration of WonderSoft’s interface. Image taken from WonderSoft’s users’ manual (Bitsmith et al., 1821).

Comment: Mention the page, too.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is, if you reference someone else, you cite them. Fortunately, there aren't many special rules about where citations are or are not allowed - they go anywhere they're appropriate.

Comment: @Klaster It's not at all necessary to include the page number. I would include it only if it was anyhow relevant or interesting. But I wouldn't ever feel obliged to do so.

Comment: Citations are also common in the captions of tables (especially tables of things like material parameters).

Comment: @yo' If taking an illustration directly out of a paper or manual, I'd definitely include the page, too. I guess it depends on the journal you submit to or your university's policy, after all.

Answer (score 22):

Unless your journal, advisor or institution insist against this (which we cannot know), **yes**, you can.

I have done this myself in publications and nobody complained.

Comment: And why should they? If the picture is taken from somewhere, providing the reference in the caption is clearly the most appropriate place!

Answer (score 10):

While you haven't mentioned the context of the citation, AFAIK, reproducing someone's graphical artifacts usually requires not only proper *citation*, but, first and foremost, **permission** from the copyright holder (author or, likely, publisher) to reproduce the artifact with or without modifications.

What it practically means is that you will need to add the following (or similar) phrase to a caption: *"Copyright ... Reproduced with permission"* (alternatively, if the artifact has been modified, instead of *"reproduced"*, use word *"adapted"*). If a permission has not yet been received, but the request has been submitted, you should add *"[pending]"* after the word *"permission"* (this is sufficient most likely only for working papers or submissions like a revision of a thesis/dissertation). Please take a look at [my relevant answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/49803/12391) for full citation example and other details.

Comment: I am using an image from this manual (page 53) http://s3.amazonaws.com/osculator/doc/OSCulator+2.12+Manual.pdf

Comment: Yes, reproducing an image requires permission of the copyright holder. However, the wording and placement of a copyright notice, if any, depends entirely on the agreement you make with the copyright holder.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I think you're wrong. The placement and wording of _copyright and permission notices_ are governed by a **publication style guide**, chosen to be used for a particular paper, not an _agreement with copyright holder_.

Comment: @user16128: As you see in the legal notices section, the guide's content is copyrighted by _Wildora_. So, in my opinion, you should contact them to request permission to use the image (or any part of content, for that matter) from that guide.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: That doesn’t make sense. You ask the copyright holder for permission, they tell you what they want in return. It’s perfectly possible they will be happy with just a “thank you” in the Acknowledgements section. On the other hand, if they insist on a formal copyright notice, they will not accept if you write it as “eeny, meeny, miny, moe” and claim that that’s your publication style guide.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: You are free to disagree with me. However, if you really want to know what is _right_ (not what _makes sense to you_), consider posting your own answer and see whether it will be upvoted or downvoted (hint: my answer seems be right, based on that criterion).